# Control structures not working with HTML tags in vscode

Tags: python, flask

making a website for a uni assignment where I have to use flask.

my app.py looks like this:

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template

@app.route ('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='KRFL Homepage')

@app.route ('/TeamCreation')
def TeamCreation(): 
    return render_template('Team_Creation.html', title='KRFL Team Creation' )
```

when i try use `{% block content %}, {% endblock %}, {% if %}, {% endif %}` or any html tag within `{% %}` it just doesn't work at all.

The base html code looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>KCFL Homepage 
        <link href ="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/style.css') }}" rel ="stylesheet">
  </title>
  </head>
    <body> 
    {% block content %}
  <h1> KRFL Homepage </h1>
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey BabaNev! Could you give a specific example of an HTML file you couldn't get to work with certain Jinja expressions?

Comment: Hi joshgalv, just loading the base page of the site where i tried using {% block content %}, {% endblock %}, didnt work and i got an internal server error

Comment: Please just add your html code and also the complete stacktrace of the error, otherwise it is basically impossible to help you

Comment: hi @Lenntror, added it